# htaccess file seems to pick up 'if contains' for a RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess

We currently have a .htaccess RewriteRule that's incorrectly (or correctly as the rule is incorrect) redirecting a URL.

**The Rule**

```
RewriteRule ^holiday-ecards/?.*$ /appindex.php [L]
```

The desired redirects for this are:

```
http://domain.com/holiday-ecards/
http://domain.com/holiday-ecards/1/
http://domain.com/holiday-ecards/1/2
http://domain.com/holiday-ecards/1/2/3
```

However, it seems to also be redirecting the following, which is undesired:

```
http://domain.com/holiday-ecards-business/
```

**EDIT**

```
/appindex.php
```

This is taking care of the app routing and works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

A number of ways you could do it, one would be setting a rewrite condition to not touch URI's that have holiday-ecards plus hyphen, like so:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/holiday-ecards-.*$
RewriteRule ^holiday-ecards/?.*$ /appindex.php [L]
```

Not sure how many variations you have of URI's with `holiday-ecards` in them.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^holiday-ecards/?.*$ /appindex.php [L]
> ```

(Note that this is an *internal rewrite*, not a redirect.)

The above `RewriteRule` *pattern* makes the slash after `holiday-ecards` optional (so it will also match `holiday-ecards-business`). However, in the example URLs that should be rewritten, the slash is mandatory. So, it would appear that you just need to make it mandatory (?), for example:

```
RewriteRule ^holiday-ecards/ /appindex.php [L]
```

The trailing pattern `.*$` is superfluous.